# How to find a row in matrix containing closest values to given vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am writing a function to find a row in matrix which is closest to given vector and given vector can be variable in size. For example if matrix size is  by 4 and vector size is 3 then function will check the first three values form each row of matrix.

For comparison, I am calculating the distance of each row in matrix from given vector and then selecting the row which has minimum distance but I think this is not perfect solution because two different row can have same minimum distance from given vector.

I would like to know that is there any built in function available in matlab. I have already tried method `ismember`.

Comment: post the code you already have as well as a numerical example of input and desired output.

Comment: what you are asking is a conceptual question not tan implementation one. Whatever function/method you use, you must be clear on the output if two rows of the matrix are equidistant from the vector.

Comment: What is your definition of distance?

Comment: I apologize to specify about distance. I am using euclidean distance for calculate

Answer (score 4):

You can compute distances with [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html), obtain the minimum, and then find all rows that have minimum distance:

```
vector = [1 3 2];
matrix = [2 1 2 2
          1 3 3 4
          0 0 0 0
          5 4 3 2];                                             %// example data
dist = pdist2(vector, matrix(:,1:numel(vector)), 'euclidean');  %// compute distances
mindist = min(dist);                                            %// minimum distance
result = find(dist==mindist);                                   %// minimizing rows
```

Change `'euclidean'` in `pdist2` to use other distance definitions.

---

Depending on your definition of distance you could use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead of `pdist2`. For example, for (squared) Euclidean distance,

```
dist = sum(bsxfun(@minus, vector, matrix(:,1:numel(vector))).^2, 2); %// squared distance
```

Comment: Nice :) didn't know `pdist2` could be used directly with matrices. was thinking about `mat2cell` and `cellfun` +1

Comment: @SanthanSalai Thanks! Yes, `pdist2` is mainly for matrices. Each row representes a "point"

Comment: Thanks. I do not have any toolbox and so I can not follow above procedure. However, I am doing almost same using for loop

Comment: @User1551892 See edit, with `bsxfun`. What's your distance definition? Euclidean?

Comment: sqrt ((matrix(1,1) -vector(1))^2 +(matrix(1,2) -vector(2))^2+(matrix(1,3) -vector(3))^2)

Comment: For Euclidean distance, the second part of my answer applies

Comment: Yeah but i have seen many solution using `pdist` for comparing 2 vectors and so i thought that way. :) BTW nice `bsxfun` edit (Y)

Comment: It seems to me that this approach is not theoretically foolproof. I am doing the same in my code using for loop instead of 'bsxfun'

Comment: What exactly is not "theoretically foolproof"?

Comment: Two rows can have same distance from target. However only one of two is truly close to target means all elements are contributing distance calculation and regarding other row, there is one element which is contributing in distance calculation. So distance of both rows are almost same.

Comment: Your claims "_Two rows can have same distance from target_" and "_only one of two is truly close_" seem contradictory to me